# How do I create this shape Using Python?

Tags: python

I need to create this shape using loops in Python:

[image]

Tried the following code:

```py
print("_________")

for i in range(1,10):
    print("" * (10- i), "*"*i,"*","*i")
```

And it results in:

[image]

Comment: [\[SO\]: Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
**[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**
for more asking related details. 
Also, [\[JonSkeet.CodeBlog\]: WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) might be a good point to start. Hint (quick and dirty): when printing, instead of comas (***,***) use pluses (***+***) and `range(0, `

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

## Python code to demonstrate star pattern

## Function to demonstrate printing pattern triangle

```
def triangle(n):
 
# number of spaces
k = n - 1

# outer loop to handle number of rows
for i in range(0, n):
 
    # inner loop to handle number spaces
    # values changing acc. to requirement
    for j in range(0, k):
        print(end=" ")
 
    # decrementing k after each loop
    k = k - 1
 
    # inner loop to handle number of columns
    # values changing acc. to outer loop
    for j in range(0, i+1):
     
        # printing stars
        print("* ", end="")
 
    # ending line after each row
    print("\r")


# Driver Code
n = 5
triangle(n)
```

**Output**

```
    * 
   * * 
  * * * 
 * * * * 
* * * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you use a `,` in the print statement. There are 2 solutions to fix it

1. Add a `sep=""` to your print statement

```py
print("<YourCode>", sep="")
```

2. Replace `,` with `+`

This is a short example of how I would do it:

```py
HIGHT = 10
for i in range(HIGHT):
    print(" " * (HIGHT - i) + "*" * (i*2+1))
```